# jQuery grep method for more than one type of filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

I am currently using the `jQuery` `$.grep()` method to filter an array by a value passed to the method like so:

```
var filteredArray = $.grep(arr, function (n, i) {
    return (n.type === type);
}, true);
```

So the array is an array of objects that have a type property and if that property is equal to the type passed to it then filter out the other objects and produce a new array from the result.

How do i extend this to accept multiple types of filters?

So if i pass an array of filters that can be a minimum length of 1 and nay maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var types = [1, 2]; // example of types...

var filteredArray = $.grep(arr, function(element) {
    return $.inArray(element.type, types) >= 0;
});

console.log(filteredArray);​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xE3Dy/3)